# Upgraded to .NET 6.0 but receiving null exception error when executing stored procedure in API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have upgraded my code from .NET Core 2.2 to .NET 6.0, after upgrading the respective packages, I am able to execute part of code, but when I try to execute the stored procedure in one of the methods, I get a System.InvalidOperationException: The required column 'RepInfoDataAgencyCode' was not present in the results of a FromSql operations.

Other methods are running fine for other stored procedure executions. I have verified in the database by executing the stored procedure manually, it works fine.

Mostly the result from stored procedure is not able to load into the model. Need help on this.

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<MentorRep>> MentorRepDetails(string userId)
    {
        var uId = new SqlParameter("@userId", userId);
        using (var ctx = _generateDbContext.GenerateNetCoreContext(_configuration))
        {
            DbSet<MentorRep> s = ctx.Set<MentorRep>();
            try
            {
                var data = await s.FromSqlRaw($"EXEC SupportingRepData @userId", uId).AsQueryable().ToListAsync();

                return data;

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Exception {ex} occured in the application ");
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
```

This is error getting from above method. System.InvalidOperationException: The required column 'RepInfoDataAgencyCode' was not present in the results of a FromSql operations.

we have no return result from SP with column 'RepInfoDataAgencyCode'.
This is populated from other class. Actually, MentorRep should be loaded by above SP, but the Repinfodata has not been loading.

```
public class MentorRep
{
    [JsonProperty("UserId")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    [JsonProperty("MenteeUserId")]
    public string MenteeUserId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ACode")]
    public string ACode { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("PRole")]
    public string PRole { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public RepInfo RepInfoData { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("AffRepTeamDetails")]`your text`
    public ICollection<TeamInfo> AffRepTeamDetails { get; set; }

    public MentorRep()
    {
        AffRepTeamDetails = new HashSet<TeamInfo>();
    }
}


modelBuilder.Entity<MentorRep>(v =>
        {
            v.HasKey(p => new { p.UserId, p.MenteeUserId });
            v.HasOne(e => e.RepInfoData)
                .WithMany(e => e.AffiliatedRepDetails);
        });
```

The below is class for RepInfo

public class RepInfo

```
{

    [JsonIgnore]

    public string TeamId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("UserId")]

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("FirstName")]

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("LastName")]

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("IPCode")]

    public string IPCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("RepStatus")]

    public string RepStatus { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("CreatedDate")]

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("LastUpdate")]

    public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("AgencyCode")]

    [Key]

    public string AgencyCode { get; set; }



    [JsonProperty("AgencyHierarchy")]

    public ICollection<AgencyData> AgencyHierarchy { get; set; }



    [JsonProperty("AffiliatedRepDetails")]

    public ICollection<MentorRep> AffiliatedRepDetails { get; set; }



    public RepInfo()

    {

        AgencyHierarchy = new HashSet<AgencyData>();

        AffiliatedRepDetails = new HashSet<MentorRep>();

    }
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: Where exactly (at which code line) do you get the exception?

Comment: var data = await s.FromSqlRaw($"EXEC Supp @userId", uId).AsQueryable().ToListAsync();   -  I am getting the error at this line of code.

Comment: You have an exception? Show us the stack trace. Is this model entity only returned by your procedure? Are you expecting the related navigations to be populated? FYI Query types changed a bit in version 3.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman, this model entity is not only returning results from procedure, in addition to result, it is expecting to load repinfo data from repinfo model and collection of objects from affrepteamdetails from Teaminfo model.

Comment: actually, i found something, missing, when i load the result from SP to model mentor, it trying to fill other column in model, which is populated by navigated to other model, that is not loading actually

Comment: Thanks for your response. You can try the solution I have provided which will allow you more flexibility in order to execute store procedure in dotnet 6 and later version.

Answer (score 0):

> Other methods are running fine for other stored procedure executions.

As per your above point, while saying, other method working fine, does other stored procedure working with parameter with the same approach?

Since ASP.NET Core 3.1 and EF Core 7.0, we ought to execute `FromSqlRaw` on entity. Regarding your shared pattern, not sure about in .NET6 version because, I haven't seen anything about this within the official document.

In addition, I have tested on .NET 6 in following official pattern and working accordingly. You could refer to the steps below:

**1.** Demo stored procedure:

[image]

**2.** Demo model class:

```
public class MentorRep
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int MenteeUserId { get; set; }
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    public string? Code { get; set; }
    public string? Status { get; set; }
}
```

**3.** DbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<MentorRep> MentorReps { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MentorRep>().ToTable("MentorRep");
    }
}
```

**4.** Controller:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ExecuteSpInDotNet6Controller : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        public ExecuteSpInDotNet6Controller(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ExecuteSpInDotNet6(int userId)
        {
            var sqlCommand = $"EXEC Supp {userId}";
            var getValueFromSp = await _context.MentorReps.FromSqlRaw(sqlCommand).ToListAsync();
            return Ok(getValueFromSp);
        }
    }
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on it you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#passing-parameters)